# Visit record USA with ESTA

Tags: usa, esta

Is there a way to check my visit record to the USA if I am travelling on an ESTA ?
I tried here: https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search
but I don't think this is the correct page and it certainly has no record of me.
Background: The airline I was travelling with made a hash of our check-in and as this was the only time (during this trip) my attempt to leave the US was recorded, I'd like to verify that the US knows I've left the country.
Edit: I travelled several times to the US within the last year, always by air. None of the trips show up. I have a fairly standard name (all ascii characters, no hyphens etc) and I've tried putting both my first name and my first and middle name in the 'first name' box, and I always get " No record found for traveler." as the error.
Another edit:
So on a whim I didn't put the country that issued the passport (Germany) in the box, but the country I live in (UK) and then it finds my records. Now German passport numbers look very different from UK ones, so I have no idea how this happened -- I thought the passport gets scanned and it collects this information automatically. I'm not impressed.

Comment: Did you last leave the US more than 5 years ago?  The dhs.gov site says that "I-94 travel history includes up to 100 arrivals and departures spanning the last five years."  It's certainly the correct page.

Comment: With regard to your edit, it now seems that we need more information to understand why your records are not being returned.  What *do* you see when you try the search?  If you have been in the US several times, why was this "the only time [your] attempt to leave the US was recorded"?  The form asks for "first (given) name"; do you have more than one of these, and, if so, did you try with all of them?

Comment: This is obviously not a duplicate because the asker knows about the I-94 site and is nonetheless having trouble finding her records.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: The link on the 'duplicate' question doesn't even work any more.

Comment: I've fixed that link.

Comment: Are sure you entering your passport number correctly (common errors include mistaking O for 0, for example; some passport numbers are alphanumeric).

Comment: Wow.  The passport number aside, the third through fifth characters on the upper line of the machine readable zone should indicate the issuing country.  For Germany, they should be `D<<`, while for the UK they should be `GBR`.  If the country you select in order to get your records doesn't match that part of your passport, it is truly baffling.

Comment: That's pretty neat. Do you have a passport from another country that you've used in the past? Their system is pretty good about collecting all of a person's travel in one list independent of the document used (they have name, birthday and fingerprints to match you to you) and I could imagine this causing country confusion for that particular UI.

Comment: No, I've never had any citizenship but Germany. And indeed my passport has the D<<